# Improvement of a C function based in igraph

Tags: c, minimum-spanning-tree, igraph

Related with the  question "Edge - weight association" and the Tamás's answer, I  wrote the below   code to get  the arc weigth of the mst tree extracted  from  the original vector weigth. I will use this code while I move to igraph 0.6.

Some one see some mistake or  improvement in the code, both general like in the igraph use.

Thanks, Guillermo.
The code:

```
int igraph_get_weight_subtree( igraph_t subtree, igraph_t grafo, igraph_vector_t vector_pesos_grafo, igraph_vector_t *vector_pesos_subtree){

igraph_vector_t vector_arcos_grafo, vector_arcos_subtree;
int i,j,k;
igraph_real_t sub_tree_nodo1, sub_tree_nodo2;

printf("\nigraph_get_weight_subtree: Imprimiendo arcos de subtree...\n");
igraph_write_graph_edgelist(&subtree, stdout);
printf("[OK]\n");

printf("\nigraph_get_weight_subtree: Imprimiendo arcos de grafo...\n");
igraph_write_graph_edgelist(&grafo, stdout);
printf("[OK]\n");

//Inicializa los vectores vector_arcos_subtree y vector_arcos_grafo
igraph_vector_init(&vector_arcos_subtree,1);
igraph_vector_init(&vector_arcos_grafo,1);

//Extrae los arcos desde los grafos de entrada. Los convierte en Vector


igraph_get_edgelist(&subtree, &vector_arcos_subtree, 0);
igraph_get_edgelist(&grafo, &vector_arcos_grafo, 0);



for (i=0; i< igraph_vector_size(&vector_arcos_subtree); i=i+2){
    sub_tree_nodo1= VECTOR(vector_arcos_subtree)[i];
    sub_tree_nodo2= VECTOR(vector_arcos_subtree)[i+1];
    //Busca arco de subtree en grafo
    j=0;
    k=0;
    while(j< igraph_vector_size(&vector_arcos_grafo)){
        if( ((sub_tree_nodo1==VECTOR(vector_arcos_grafo)[j])&& (sub_tree_nodo2==VECTOR(vector_arcos_grafo)[j+1]))|| ((sub_tree_nodo2==VECTOR(vector_arcos_grafo)[j])&&(sub_tree_nodo1==VECTOR(vector_arcos_grafo)[j+1]))) {
            igraph_vector_push_back (vector_pesos_subtree, VECTOR(vector_pesos_grafo)[k]);
            break;
        }//End if
        j=j+2;
        k=k+1;
    }//End while
}

//Destruye los vectore en desuso
igraph_vector_destroy(&vector_arcos_subtree);
igraph_vector_destroy(&vector_arcos_grafo);

return 0;
}
```